# ¿Como recupero un parametro de una url de postman en python y django?

Tags: python, django, api, postman, parametros

Pues eso, tengo esta url en postman:

```
{{HOST}}/api/v1/tracking/sensor/data/1/
```

Y quiero recuperar el 1 que esta al final, porque lo quiero almacenar en una variable.

Tambien tengo esta llamada en urls.py, para que pueda ejecutar la funcion a la hora de hacer el PATCH:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/v1/tracking/sensor/data/:id', tracking_views.DatastoreAPI.patch),
]
```

El problema es que no se como hacer que el `:id` sea leido como un parametro cambiante, como se hacia en javascript (puesto que para sacar el parametro se usa `req.params.id` con esa url)

En el metodo `patch` de `DatastoreAPI` quiero ejecutar la funcion

Answer (score 1):

Deberías definir tu url como

```
path('api/v1/tracking/sensor/data/<int:id>/', tracking_views.DatastoreAPI.patch)
```

Puedes ver la [documentacion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/) para mas detalles.

En tu vista deberías poder acceder al parámetro como:

```
def patch(self, request, id):
    return HttpResponse(f'the id is {id}')
```

Comment: Si funcionó, pero le tuve que eliminar el ````self```` para que me pueda leer los parametros